# GUI Matlab, plotting a sound wav from listbox

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a matlab GUI, In my listbox there is wav sounds.I want to choose a sound and plot it after playing.

Comment: Please read this guide about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly. It would immensely increase the chance that you receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Arpi your question is quite broad and could have been formulated more clearly with examples of what you tried and what did not work.

That being said I'm feeling generous so here is some sample code to get you started. There is a listbox with a pushbutton and an axes. You basically select a sound and then push the button to plot the signal and play the sound. I use the demo `handel.mat` sound file from Matlab. You can fill the rest with your own data and see how it works.For instance I store the data from the sound file in a cell array in since your data will likely be of different sizes.

You can copy this code in a new .m file and run it. I commented it but if you have questions please ask.

```
function PlaySound_GUI
clc
clear
close all

%// Create GUI components
hfigure = figure('Position',[100 100 500 500],'Units','Pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[60,90,400,300]);

handles.SoundString = {'Handel' ;'Sound 1'; 'Sound 2'};
handles.LB = uicontrol('Style','Listbox','Position',[60 420 100 60],'String',handles.SoundString,'Value',1,'Callback',@(s,e) ListBoxCallback);

handles.PlayButton = uicontrol('Style','Push','Position',[200 420 60 30],'String','Play sound','Value',1,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9],'Callback',@(s,e) PlayCallback);

%// Load sounds and place their data in a cell array. Seems complicated but
%// you can simplify by storing everything into the handles structure.

handles.SoundCellArray = cell(3,2);

HandelSound = load('handel.mat');

handles.SoundCellArray{1,1} = HandelSound.y;
handles.SoundCellArray{1,2} = HandelSound.Fs;

guidata(hfigure,handles);

%// Listbox callback. Check what sound is selected
    function ListBoxCallback()

        handles = guidata(hfigure);

        handles.SoundSelected = handles.SoundString{get(handles.LB,'value')};

        guidata(hfigure,handles);

    end
    function PlayCallback()

        handles = guidata(hfigure);

        %// Plot and play selected sound.
        switch handles.SoundSelected

            case 'Handel'

                N = length(handles.SoundCellArray{1,1});

                t = linspace(0, N/handles.SoundCellArray{1,2}, N);

                plot(t,handles.SoundCellArray{1,1})

                %// Play sound
                sound(handles.SoundCellArray{1,1},handles.SoundCellArray{1,2});

            case 'Sound 1'

              %// For the demo there is nothing here...

            case 'Sound 2'


              %// For the demo there is nothing here...
        end

        guidata(hfigure,handles);
    end
end
```

And sample screenshot of the output:

[image]

Have fun with the rest!

Comment: I have a button in my GUI when I press it, the wav sound in a specific folder will be listed in a listbox. so I will play a sound from the listbox and then press a plot button that plots the sound I'm playing. That's my code: 
function Display_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
d = dir('c:\monitoringsystem'); %get files
set(handles.listbox1,'String',{d.name})

Comment: function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
allstrings = cellstr( get(handles.listbox1, 'String') );
curvalue = get(handles.listbox1, 'Value');
thisstring = allstrings{curvalue};
[q, Fs] = audioread(thisstring);
 sound(q, Fs);

Comment: I want to plot it in an axes, so please any help.

Comment: Isn't that was I just showed in my answer? Surely you can work from that right?

Comment: In your program, the listed sound is composed from an array. But,my program I'm using the listbox as adirectory, what is in a folder will be listed in the listbox. I want to put a button(plot) which will plot the selected sound.  Please any help